# Handle URL Parameters on Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I Have a GET API

```
{END_POINT}api/apps?
redirectsTo=https://example.com/Home/Error?fromPage=conf&status=404
&uid=123
```

The problem was below key value is a single param

```
redirectsTo=https://example.com/Home/Error?fromPage=conf&status=400
```

But internally I have `status` as `boolean` param with DTO validation on a controller,
All the time it gets status param from `redirectsTo` param value and validates as an invalid param. How to handle this on Node js Typescript.

I don't want to pick status param from redirectsTo param how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encode it on client side before making a request:

```
const redirectsTo = encodeURIComponent('https://example.com/Home/Error?fromPage=conf&status=404');
```

and then pass it as a query param to the request.

Then on the Node.js side you can decode it using a built-in [`querystring`](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystringunescapestr) module:

```
const qs = require('querystring');
qs.unescape(...); // pass your encoded string here
```